# Data sent from form in view is not being received in the form

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a form that is just a checkbox and hidden inputs (to send data back to the controller) as follows:

```
    @model List<UserRoleViewModel>


@{
    var roleId = ViewBag.roleId;
}


<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddOrRemoveUsers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2> Add or remove users from this role</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                <div class="form-check m-1">
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].UserName" />
                    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].UserId" />
                    <input asp-for="@Model[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
                    <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model[i].IsSelected">
                        @Model[i].UserName
                    </label>
                </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />
                <a asp-action="ListRoles" class="btn btn-primary"> Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I expect to get the data in this controller:

```
    public class AdminController : Controller
    {
        private readonly RoleManager<IdentityRole> _roleManager;
        private readonly UserManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser> _userManager;


        public AdminController(RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager, UserManager<Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.IdentityUser> userManager)
        {
            _roleManager = roleManager;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrRemoveUsers(string roleId)
        {
            ViewBag.roleId = roleId;

            var role = _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

            if (role == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"The Role with roleId = {roleId} cannot be found";
                return View("Not found");
            }

            var model = new List<UserRoleViewModel>();

            var AllUser = _userManager.Users;
            var UserInThisRole = await _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(role.Result.Name);

            foreach (var user in AllUser)
            {
                var userRoleViewModel = new UserRoleViewModel
                { 
                    UserId = user.Id,
                    UserName = user.UserName,
                    IsSelected = false

                };
                if (UserInThisRole.Any(p=>p.Id == userRoleViewModel.UserId))
                {
                    userRoleViewModel.IsSelected = true;
                }
                model.Add(userRoleViewModel);
            }

            return View(model);
        }

[HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrRemoveUsers([FromForm]List<UserRoleViewModel> model, string roleId) 
        {
            var role = _roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

            if (role == null)
            {
                ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"The Role with roleId = {roleId} cannot be found";
                return View("Not found");
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < model.Count; i++)
            {
                var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(model[i].UserId);

                IdentityResult result = null;

                if (model[i].IsSelected && !(await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Result.Name)))
                {
                    result = await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, role.Result.Name);
                }
                else if (!model[i].IsSelected && await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Result.Name))
                {
                    result = await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, role.Result.Name);

                }
                else
                {
                    continue;
                }

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    if (i < (model.Count - 1))
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("ListRoles");   
                    }
                }

            }

            return RedirectToAction("ListRoles");

            }
    } 
}
```

But when I add a breakpoint on the controller, I can only see the `roleId` the `model` has `count=0`, even though there are values being sent to the back end if you check the request data.

[image: The form data being sent from front-end]

The userRoleViewModel

```
namespace BataCMS.ViewModels
{
    public class UserRoleViewModel
    {
        public string UserId;
        public string UserName;
        public bool IsSelected;
    }
}
```

Any insights on what might be causing this?

Comment: According to your description and codes, I have created a test demo on my side, it works well. I used @model List<UserRoleViewModel> as the view model and I could get the model in the action. Could you please tell me which model you have used in your view?  Could you please tell me how you pass the roleid by using query string?

Comment: I used List<UserRoleViewModel> in the role and the roleId is coming from the query string

Comment: I also used the List<UserRoleViewModel> as the model and I could get the item. [Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UF1k6.png). I suggest you could try to post the whole view and whole controller for us to reproduce the issue on our side.

Comment: Added tho whole view and the complete action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your view codes, I found you don't add the tag helper. Without tag helper, the aspnet core will not renter the asp-for attribute in the input tag. This is the reason why you don't receive the model in the action method.

To solve this issue, I suggest you could try to add below codes in the view and then it will work well.

```
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Details, you could refer to below view codes:

```
@model List<CoreNormalIssue.Controllers.UserRoleViewModel>
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers


@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>AddOrRemoveUsers</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="post">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h2> Add or remove users from this role</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
                {
                    <div class="form-check m-1">
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].UserName" />
                        <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model[i].UserId" />
                        <input asp-for="@Model[i].IsSelected" class="form-check-input" />
                        <label class="form-check-label" asp-for="@Model[i].IsSelected">
                            @Model[i].UserName
                        </label>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Update" />
                <a asp-action="ListRoles" class="btn btn-primary"> Cancel</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image]

UserViewModel:

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{

    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }

}
```

Mytest Action:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddOrRemoveUsers(string roleId)
    {
        ViewBag.roleId = roleId;

        List<UserRoleViewModel> model = new List<UserRoleViewModel>() {
         new UserRoleViewModel(){ UserId="test1", UserName="testname1", IsSelected=true },
         new UserRoleViewModel(){ UserId="test2", UserName="testname2" , IsSelected=false },
         new UserRoleViewModel(){ UserId="test3", UserName="testname3", IsSelected=true }

        }; 
        return View(model);
    }
```

---

Update:

I found your userviewmodel used field not the properties. Asp.net core model binding doesn't support field.

You should use below viewmodel and then it will work well.

```
public class UserRoleViewModel
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: I already had the tag helper in the _ViewImports file. And even if I add the tag helper to the view I am still getting the same problem.

Comment: but i do wonder on the model you used `@model List<CoreNormalIssue.Controllers.UserRoleViewModel>` where it comes from and what it is about

Comment: I created a test UserRoleViewModel in the controller to test. It is very simple. You could see my updated codes. Have you checked the  UserRoleViewModel has value in the AddOrRemoveUsers view?

Comment: Yes I did, they have values in the view

Comment: Could you please post the details userviewmodel? Besides, do you have any global custom model biding in your project?  If there is no other things, I suggest you could try to create a small project or make sure there is no personal data and upload the project to the github for us to test.

Comment: I made an edit to show the details of the userRoleViewModel. And I have already uploaded on  [github](https://github.com/Gudu4Real/BataCMS/tree/GitIssue%238) I'm currently working on the gitissue#8.branch

Comment: You should use the properties instead of the field. Then it will work well. See my update answer.

Comment: I can't believe it was this simple and staring me right in the face. Thank you much appreciated.